# Critical t values in R

Tags: r

I need to determine the critical t values for one-sided tails of 75% and 99%, for 40 degrees of freedom.

The following is code for a two-sided 99% critical t values:

```
qt(0.01, 40)
```

but how can I determine for a one-sided critical t value?

Comment: What makes you think that `qt(0.01, 40)` is the critical value for the two-sided test? I'd suggest reading `?qt`, and then thinking a bit more about what one- and two-sided tests mean.

Comment: Really this is a question on understanding what those critical values actually mean.  This is more of a statistical question and probably should be migrated to the stats stackexchange site.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The code you posted gives the critical value for a one-sided test (Hence the answer to you question is simply:

```
abs(qt(0.25, 40)) # 75% confidence, 1 sided (same as qt(0.75, 40))
abs(qt(0.01, 40)) # 99% confidence, 1 sided (same as qt(0.99, 40))
```

Note that the t-distribution is symmetric. For a 2-sided test (say with 99% confidence) you can use the critical value

```
abs(qt(0.01/2, 40)) # 99% confidence, 2 sided
```

Answer (score 5):

Josh's comments are spot on.  If you are not super familiar with critical values I'd suggest playing with qt, reading the manual (`?qt`) in conjunction with looking at a look up table ([LINK](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_5u1UHojRiJk/TEdJJc6of2I/AAAAAAAAAIE/Ai0MW5VgIhg/s1600/t-table.jpg)).  When I first moved from SPSS to R I created a function that made critical t value look up pretty easy (I'd never use this now as it takes too much time and with the p values that are generally provided in the output it's a moot point).  Here's the code for that:

```
critical.t <- function(){
    cat("\n","\bEnter Alpha Level","\n")
    alpha<-scan(n=1,what = double(0),quiet=T)
    cat("\n","\b1 Tailed or 2 Tailed:\nEnter either 1 or 2","\n")
    tt <- scan(n=1,what = double(0),quiet=T)
    cat("\n","\bEnter Number of Observations","\n")
    n <- scan(n=1,what = double(0),quiet=T)
    cat("\n\nCritical Value =",qt(1-(alpha/tt), n-2), "\n")
}

critical.t()
```

Comment: n-2 as your degrees of freedom with no option to change it?  Sounds like you only used it for simple linear regression?

Comment: Spot on it was Stats I.  But that sounds like where the poster is at too.

Answer (score 3):

Extending @Ryogi answer above, you can take advantage of the `lower.tail` parameter like so:

`qt(0.25/2, 40, lower.tail = FALSE)` # 75% confidence

`qt(0.01/2, 40, lower.tail = FALSE)` # 99% confidence